# Android, Как сохранить файл во внутреннюю память, не в кэш или папки приложения?

Tags: android, файлы, kotlin

Kotlin. В приложении надо добавить вариант сохранить данные в файл, для того чтобы их куда хочет пользователь перекидывать или открывать в других приложениях.
Соответственно в context?.getExternalFilesDir("Data") и подобные файл сохраняется прекрасно, но во-первых это не очевидные папки для пользователя во вторых эти папки не доступны для других приложений, да и после удаления приложения эти папки тоже удаляются.
Но при попытке сохранить куда-то во внутренне хранилище получаю ошибку "open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Не дают никакого эффекта

Comment: getExternalFilesDir файлы доступны для других приложений

Comment: @Style-7 c Scoped Storage нет, https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Comment: @IR42 На практике для Андроид 11 все работает (тестировал)

Comment: @Style-7 не знаю, у меня тоже получилось прочитать чужую data, но только на андройд 9 (таргет 30), на андройд 11 уже ошибку выбивает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться MediaStore API.

Написал примерно такой код и он работает:

```
val values = ContentValues()
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "savedFromCalorieTrackKLite") //file name
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain") //file extension, will automatically add to file
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/CalorieTrackKLite/") //end "/" is not mandatory
val uri = getActivity()?.getContentResolver()?.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), values) //important!
val outputStream = getActivity()?.getContentResolver()?.openOutputStream(uri!!)
outputStream?.write(toFile.toString().toByteArray())
outputStream?.close()
```